# Safari / Firefox on Mac not rendering &middot; properly

Tags: macos, fonts

I have some text that looks like this:

```
Some Text&nbsp;&middot;&nbsp;SomeMoreText
```

In all Windows browsers, this shows up like:

[image]

But on the Mac, it shows up like:

[image]

Why does the Mac trim the space following the dot? Even `&nbsp;` doesn't work.

Comment: What font are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the font you're using (Arial Black). For some reason there seems to be an issue with the kerning on the mid-dot character in the Mac version of this font. You'll need to use a different font to fix this issue.

Comment: I figured as much too. However, when I view Arial Black in the fontbook app, it looks fine.